# OSX Bash: Dynamically rename files found from list

Tags: bash, macos, sed, find

I have tried searching for similar questions but can't find anything so apologies if this or similar has been asked before.

I am writing a script to read a textfile list of file names with a reference number then looking through subfolders for those files, then amending the name to include the ref num.

The text file will look like this (tab delimited and with header) :

```
"File Name (without Extension)"  "Media Number"
"AK7A7964"  "01017134"
"IMG_0026"  "01017192"
"106491 Anenome"  "01017206"
"CW1_9449"  "01017243"
```

I am using this to clean the file of \t and ":

```
 cat $file | sed "1 d" | tr "\\t" "," | sed 's/\"//g' > $cleanfile
```

Then reading the cleanfile into a while loop:

```
INPUT=$cleanfile
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read fname media; do
```

And constructing the new name to be amended to the start of the filename

```
newFileName="MA_${media}_"
```

I'm then doing  a find for each file with that name using:

```
for found in $(find . -type f  -name "$fname.*" ); do
```

but when I try to amend the name, it only alters the last result if there are multiple files with the same name found.

I'm probably missing a trick in doing this using `sed` but I can't find a guide that doesn't go off in the deep end quite quickly!

**[edit to add]**

What I was doing after the last `do` was this: 
Getting the path and basename, creating the new file name, then using `mv` to replace it. I was actually just doing an `echo` so it was non-destructive

```
foundPath="${found%/*}"
foundFile="${found##*/}"

newFile=$newFileName$foundFile
newFilePath="${foundPath}/${newFile}"
mv $found $newFilePath
```

If there was more than one occurrence of any filename (as there will be), it was only `mv`'ing the last one.

Comment: it would be helpful if you included what you're doing after `do` in your loops.

Comment: The loop won't work if the name has a space in it, like `106491 Anenome`.

Comment: How is your `while read` loop using `,` as the delimiter between `fname` and `media`?

Comment: Also you don't need `cat`. `sed "1 d" "$file" | tr "\\t" "," | sed 's/\"//g' > "$cleanfile"`

Comment: @user556068 Ive updated the details of whats happening after in the `for found in $(find . -type f  -name "$fname.*" ); do` section

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your title. Marking an answer as accepted is the way to indicate so. And you already did that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was this:

`find . -type f -name "${fname}.*" -exec sh -c 'for i; do name=${i##*/} path=${i%/*}; mv "$i" "$path/MA_${media}_$name"; done' _ {} +`